# C/C++ library for non-intrusive user-friendly configuration

Tags: open-source, c++, c, web

I am looking for a C or C++ open-source library for exposing configuration-related variable via an API and a web UI. The requirements are:

**R1. It should be non-intrusive for the programmer.** Assume an existing code has a global variable `const bool show_fps = false` (i.e., a debugging relic), a programmer should be able to write something like:

```
bool show_fps = true;  // only "const" is removed
CONFIG(&show_fps,  // variable
    "debug.show_fps",  // API identifier
    "Show FPS",  // short user-friendly title
    "Enable/disable displaying the number of frames per second of the video pipeline",  // long user-friendly description
);
```

**R2. It should expose an API (e.g., REST, line-oriented) which allows:**

- to list configuration variables, their user-friendly title and their description;
- to determine their current value;
- to set the value of a variable.

**R3. It should expose a single-page web UI which present the above API in a user-friendly manner.**

---

Since, I got the question previously: I know that C and C++ are not the same thing, however, I believe that writing an adapter from one language to another implies a lot less effort that writing a library fulfilling the above requirements from scratch. Hence, I am open to both C and C++ libraries.

---

Below are some examples of libraries and frameworks I came across during my research and why they fall short:

- Boost `program_options` fits R1 quite nicely:

  ```
  int opt;
  po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
  desc.add_options()
      ("optimization", po::value<int>(&opt)->default_value(10), "optimization level")
  ;
  ```

  However, it seems to be geared towards the command-line, environment variables and configuration files, hence not fulfilling R2 and R3.
- I drew a lot of inspiration from the Linux kernel's `moduleparam.h` header:

  ```
  static int max_loop;
  module_param(max_loop, int, 0444);
  MODULE_PARM_DESC(max_loop, "Maximum number of loop devices");
  ```

  It fits requirement R1 quite well. R2 is almost fulfilled, i.e., said configuration can be manipulated via sysfs, however, an API that is not kernel-specific is required. R3 is not fulfilled.
- [etcd](https://coreos.com/etcd/) is an excellent server-software for storing key-value configuration variables organized as a tree, partially fulfilling R2 and R3. However, it does not have a notion of user-friendly title and description for each variable. Furthermore, I found no library to integrate with it non-intrusively (R1).

Comment: Welcome aboard. This is a great question (+1). Unfortunately, I don't know the answer, but I do hope that someone else does, as this could be very useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own library under a MIT license. If anybody ever has the same problem feel free to use it: https://github.com/cristiklein/cpprestconfig

Contributions welcome!